# Tunnel through center of the earth, how to find period using $ adx=vdv$?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, kinematics

Suppose the boulder enters a tunnel dug through the center of the Earth along a diameter starting at rest. How would one calculate the time it takes for the boulder to reach the other end of the tunnel using $adx=vdv$?

I know how to approach a problem like this using $$a=-\omega^2⋅x$$ 
And I would like to understand how to do this problem using kinematics.

Suppose we already know that $$a=G\frac{M}{R^3}r$$
How would one do the rest?

Comment: What you have written already solves the problem since we immediately read off $\omega^2 = \frac{GM}{R^3}$ and $T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega}$. What more do are you looking for?

Comment: I would like to a see a solution to the problem using $$adx=vdv$$ I know that what I have written shows an obvious solution but I am not able to prove it using my knowledge of kinematics.

Comment: Oh! You want a proof that if $a = - \omega^2 x$ then $T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega}$. Is that right?

Comment: Not really. This is what I need help with:
$$-\int_{R}^{0}G\frac{M}{R^3}r dr=\int_{0}^{v_f}vdv$$
This would give me velocity at the center of the Earth. How would I go about finding the time it takes to get there using kinematics. Would I use $$v=\frac{dx}{dt}$$ I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: Strictly speaking the harmonic oscillator problem is a dynamics, not a kinematics problem, isn't it? The forces acting on the particle depend on the location of the particle... and unless there is some loophole in the definition of kinematics as "Kinematics is the branch of classical mechanics which describes the motion of points, bodies (objects), and systems of bodies (groups of objects) without consideration of the causes of motion.", I don't see how it can be derived with this restriction.

Comment: Oh so it's not possible to derive?

Comment: @SaagarGodithi - Of course you can derive. You would indeed use $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$ and integrate this.

Comment: It's trivial to derive, all I am saying is that I don't know if it can be derived within the confines of not using the driving forces for the motion, which would put it into "dynamics", by definition. Nor do I know what purpose it may serve to derive it with kinematics alone... I have never seen that requirement in a practical problem. Having said that, it may be interesting for teaching purposes.

Comment: I'm sorry if my phrasing was unclear i didn't mean with the restriction of kinematics. Would you mind showing steps to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$adx=vdv$$
$$-\int_{R}^{x}G\frac{M}{R^3}xdx=\int_{0}^{v}vdv$$
$$v=\sqrt{2 (-\frac{GMx^2}{2R^3}+\frac{GM}{2R})}$$
$$v=\frac{dx}{dt}$$
$$t-0=2\int_{0}^{R}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 (-\frac{GMx^2}{2R^3}+\frac{GM}{2R})}}dx$$
$$t=1267.5s$$